# Error merging files: . Error says that variable CLAIM_NUMBER does not uniquely identify observations in the using data. How do I fix that?

Tags: merge, stata, stata-macros, readstata13

In Stata, the error says that variable CLAIM_NUMBER does not uniquely identify observations in the using data. How do I fix that?
My code:

````
cd"abcd"
use NY2019_2021
merge m:1 CLAIM_NUMBER using FULLNY
keep if _merge==3
drop _merge```
````

Comment: The answer to this depends on your data. Either you need to `merge` on more variables than one, or there is a problem with duplicates in your data. Without an example of your data, we can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to drop the ones that weren't unique
code:

```
duplicates list CLAIM_NUMBER
duplicates drop CLAIM_NUMBER, force
```